# Convert dataframe to mids using mice in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I have use mice to impute data, save the data as csv, and then run a Factor Analysis in SPSS and generated some factors. I now want to load the csv in R and run an imputed linear regression on the data. However, when I try to convert the dataframe to mids I get and error message saying:

```
library(mice)

# assign mtcars to a new dataframe
df <- mtcars

# loop 10 times
for (x in 1:10){
  
  # create a fake imp number
  a <- rep(x, 1, nrow(df))
  
  # bind the fake imp number to the df
  df2 <- cbind(df, a)
  
  # crate a 10 folded version of mtcars with also the fake imp number
  if (x ==1){
    new_df <- df2
  } else{
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, df2)
  }
}

# change the column name of the fake imp to ".imp"
names(new_df)[names(new_df) == 'a'] <- '.imp'

# convert df to mids
df_imp <- as.mids(new_df, .imp = .imp)

> Error in as.mids(df) : Original data not found. Use `complete(...,
> action = 'long', include = TRUE)` to save original data.
```

Can you please help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

From the `as.mids()` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.14.0/topics/as.mids).

> This function converts imputed data stored in long format into an object of class mids. **The original incomplete dataset needs to be available so that we know where the missing data are**. The function is useful to convert back operations applied to the imputed data back in a mids object. It may also be used to store multiply imputed data sets from other software into the format used by mice.

The incomplete data is stored as imputation 0 in the long format. Therefore starting your procedure at 0 instead of 1 resolves the issue. (Also, you need quotes around `.imp = '.imp'` in the `as.mids()` call. Or, remove it and rely on the default. Or, just supply "a" as the imputation variable.)

```r
library(mice)
df <- mtcars
for (x in 0:10){
  a <- rep(x, 1, nrow(df))
  df2 <- cbind(df, a)
  if (x == 0){
    new_df <- df2
  } else{
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, df2)
  }
}
names(new_df)[names(new_df) == 'a'] <- '.imp'
df_imp <- as.mids(new_df)
```